# Atomic operations in C, not C++

Tags: c, atomic

A C++ program handled atomic instructions

```c
#include <bits/atomic_word.h>
#include <ext/atomicity.h>
...
_Atomic_word use_count;
...
__gnu_cxx::__exchange_and_add_dispatch
```

but if I change `main.cpp` to `main.c`, the headers are not found. These are in the `/usr/include/c++/9` directory. However, the Linux kernel was written in C, not C++, and some structures must have atomicity. How to enable atomicity, especially without asm code?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic

Comment: You shouldn't be using those headers from a C++ program either. In C++, `#include <atomic>`. In C, `#include <stdatomic.h>`

Comment: The linux kernel has its own constructs for dealing with atomicity due to issues with compilers and performance requirements. C atomics should only be used where approved for use. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0124r5.html

Answer (score 2):

The code you're seeing is GCC-specific extensions that were sometimes used before atomic types made it into the C11 and C++11 standards.

Modern portable C code should use the types and functions in the `<stdatomic.h>` header, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic and references therein.  C++ should use the `std::atomic<T>` types from the `<atomic>` header, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic.

The Linux kernel actually doesn't use the standard C atomics, but creates its own, based on inline assembly, compiler builtins, and internal knowledge about how GCC generates code (beyond what the C standard promises). There is some discussion [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/691128/) about the reasons for this: partly because the Linux atomics code predates the C11 standard and good-quality support in compilers, partly because it's based on a different memory model than C11 is.  Anyway, it's not a good model for userspace programs.